# What is the meaning of "has U.S. president" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "has U.S. president" in the following sentence,

> No matter what happens, President Donald Trump won’t have the shortest
> tenure **has U.S. president**.
>
> At the moment, Trump has served 118 days in office, as impeachment
> talk is in the air, at least slightly, after a report he told the
> former director of the Federal Bureau of Investigation to drop a probe
> into Trump’s former national security adviser.

?

Source: https://www.marketwatch.com/story/no-matter-what-trump-wont-have-record-for-the-shortest-term-in-office-2017-05-17

Does "President Donald Trump won’t have the shortest tenure has U.S. president" mean "President Donald Trump won't have the shortest tenure among U.S. president" ?

Does "has U.S president" mean "among U.S president" ?

What does "at least slightly, after a report~ " mean "right after a report~" ?

Answer (score 6):

> has U.S. president.

That's a typo. Should read "as U.S. president".

> What does "at least slightly" mean?

It refers to the previous phrase "impeachment talk is in the air".

Comment: If so, "Trump has served 118 days in office, as impeachment talk is in the air, at least slightly, after a report" mean "Trump has served 118 days in office, as impeachment talk is in the air, impeachment talk is in the air, after a report" ? If so, can we remove "at least slightly" from the sentence?

Comment: If your question is "can we remove 'at least slightly' from the sentence" -  yes.